# how to avoid duplicated values in laravel validation?

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I have a question about `distinct` validation rule of Laravel.
I have read the docuimentation and I read the `distinct` rule description.
But I didn't get proper result by using that.
I want to avoid sending duplicated values in a request,
so I added the rule like this:

```
'versions.*.pattern' => [
    'string' ,'required_with:modifiers', 'distinct:versions.*.pattern'
]
```

But it passes the values even if they are repeated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need to repeat your validation key (`versions.*.pattern`) after `distinct:`. `'distinct'` suffices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment . Have you tried this way before ? I didn't get my answer this way too

Comment: I haven't. But the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-distinct) hints that if you use `distinct` with a colon, you can only use that in combination with either `strict` or `ignore_case` as value behind the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's just 'distinct' :

```
'versions.*.pattern' => [
    'string' ,'required_with:modifiers', 'distinct'
]
```

the arguments after `:` is for `strict` or `ignore_case`

Comment: can you make a dd(request()->all()) of your request and post it in your original post ?

Answer (score 0):

Mathieu's answer is correct. If it's not working, you'd need to share an example request payload that isn't producing the desired result.

Note that if you're using `versions.*.pattern` it assumes a data structure like this:

```
['versions' => [
  ['pattern' => 'x'],
  ['pattern' => 'y'],
]]
```

In that example, versions is an array of arrays where the third level array has a key called pattern. If you don't actually have a 3-level array like that, it would be helpful to see your actual request formatting to propose the correct rule.